# Sending Data from MainWindow to Another Dialog in QT

Tags: qt

I am trying to set up code to send data from my MainWindow to another Dialog but couldnt get it working.

MainWindow.h

```
signals:
     void send_data(QString a);
```

MainWindow.cpp
under main-

```
 QObject::connect(this, &MainWindow::send_data, Parameters, &parameters::recieved);

void MainWindow::showtime(){
 
 emit send_data(travel_c);
}
```

parameters UI

```
public slots:
    void revieved(QString a);


void parameters::recieved(QString a) {


    ui->START_DELAY->setText(a);
    qDebug()<<"Recieved"<<a;
}
```

I am unable to get the output and recieving this error
QObject::connect: No such slot parameters::recieved()
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'parameters')

Comment: As far as I'm aware the error message shown -- `"QObject::connect: No such slot ..."` can't be due to the code shown.  Instead it's generated at runtime by `connect` calls that use the old `SIGNAL`/`SLOT` macros.

Comment: Yes ,you are right ,It is generated at runtime, When the parameters Ui Is called.